# How to run gulp project on Windows IIS, or Linux server for production?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

How to deploy my code  on Windows  IIS. What library I use for running my project on production environment? What command I run for production.  I am new in AngularJS, I am using gulp project. Anyone help me please? Here is my gulp file, I want to deploy this code on Windows IIS, or other Linux server.

> my code ruining on PORT 3000  command :  gulp serve

```
'use strict';


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Dependencies
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var gulp         = require('gulp');
var watch        = require('gulp-watch');
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync');
var runSequence  = require('run-sequence');
var concat       = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify')
var reload       = browserSync.reload;


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SASS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./scss/ltr-app.scss', './scss/rtl-app.scss'])
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// JavaScript
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    './bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
    './bower_components/angular-translate-handler-log/angular-translate-handler-log.js',

    './bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    './bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js',
    './bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js',

    './bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',

    './app/app.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Watch Files & Reload
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(['./index.html'], [reload]);
  gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', ['sass', reload]);
  gulp.watch('./app/app.js', ['js', reload]);
});


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Build
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('build', [], function() {
  runSequence('sass', 'js');
});


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Gulp Default
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

gulp.task('default', [], function() {
  gulp.start('serve');
});
```